# ¿Por qué me marca error de longitud en el array?

Tags: java

Estoy codificando un programa que capture el promedio de calificaciones de un alumno que lleva 11 materias, y las muestre en orden inverso a como fueron tecleadas.

El error que tengo dice:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 11 out of bounds for length 11

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    double calif[] = new double[11];
    double promedio ;
    
    int a = 0;
    do {
        promedio = leer.nextDouble();
        calif[a] = promedio;
     
        a++;
    } while (a < calif.length);

    promedio = calif[a] / 11;
    System.out.println("promedio = " + promedio);
    System.out.println(calif[a]);
}
```

Comment: Intenta usar  ``a < calif.length-1`` ya que el arreglo tiene 11, pero se empieza por el 0, por lo tanto no existe ``calif[11]``, y el ``do-while`` primero ejecuta y después comprueba.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tu arreglo tiene 11 números pero 10 posiciones,el valor de "a" indica la posición en el arreglo, la ultima iteración de este toma el valor de 11,por eso te marca error.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    double calif[] = new double[11];
    double promedio ;
    double suma=0;
    int a = 0;
    do {
        promedio = leer.nextDouble();
        calif[a] = promedio;
          suma+=calif[a];
        a++;
        
    } while (a < calif.length);

    promedio = suma / 11;
   
    System.out.println("promedio = " + promedio);
    
}
```

Comment: otro dato aunque puedes realizar esta división, calif[a] / 11, esto solo dividira el numero que se encuentra en la posicion [a], no toda la suma del arreglo

Answer (score 2):

Lo ultimo que haces antes de salir del do..while es incrementar a.
En ese momento a es igual a 11 y sales del loop

Pero en la siguiente linea tienes `calif[a]` y es decir calif[11] y ahi es cuando estas fuera del rango.

Las opciones:

1. Inicializar a con `int a=-1;`, mover el `a++` al inicio del loop y terminar el while con `while (a <= calif.length)`
2. al terminar el while comparar `if(a>calif.length) a--;`